A question regarding the distributed RC π model
In Rabaey's Digital Integrated Circuits: A Design Perspective, Figure 4.62 shows the  distributed RC network to be modeled after the π model. What I'm unclear is for the π3 model, the capacitance is distributed as 6/3/3/6 instead of evenly (4/4/4/4). By hand calculation, with the 6/3/3/6 distribution, the Elmore delay will be \$\tau_D1=RC/9 + 2RC/9+1RC/6=RC/2\$, whereas with the 4/4/4/4 distribution I also obtain \$\tau_D2=RC/12 + 2RC/12+RC/4=RC/2\$.  Both types of distribution eventually produce the same Elmore delay, so why is the 4/4/4/4 not considered, or is the 6/3/3/6 superior by any mean?


As the cell count in the Elmore modeled network increases, the calculation with evenly distributed Cs (in your modified pi model) or Rs (in the modified tee model, if you like) becomes still more complicated, defeating the very purpose of the pi/tee model introduction.
Note that C/3 of the pi3 model is in fact two parallel C/6 capacitors, each of which belongs in the adjacent cells. Likewise, R/3 of the tee3 model is just two serial R/6 resistors of adjoining tee-cells.
In general, the piN cell is
Cleft NODE_IN GND C/(2*N) 
Rpi NODE_IN NODE_OUT R/3 
Cright NODE_OUT GND C/(2*N) 

Likewise, the teeN cell is
Rleft NODE_IN NODE_CENTER R/(2*N) 
Ctee NODE_CENTER GND C/N 
Rright NODE_CENTER NODE_OUT R/(2*N)

